# Dropbox core API copy_ref showing (404) Not Found error

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to copy a file from a dropbox to another user's Dropbox.
I'm calling the Dropbox core API v1 copy_ref to get the response like

```
RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Get
                  (
                    "https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/copy_ref/auto",
                    new HttpParameterCollection
                {
                  {"access_token", "AccessToken"},
                  {"path", Path.Combine("CurrentPath", "FileName").Replace("\\", "/")}
                }
                  );
```

It is showing me error "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found"
I'm unable to find where is the mistake committed.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206790746-copy-ref-showing-404-Not-Found-error ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making an HTTP request to `https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/copy_ref/auto`, but it should be `https://api.dropboxapi.com/1/copy_ref/auto/path/to/the/file`. (You should then remove the `path` parameter you're using in the `HttpParameterCollection`.)

(See the documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#copy_ref.)